# Can a point be closer to all the vertices of a convex polytope than another point inside that polytope?

Tags: normed-spaces, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, polytopes

Consider a set $X = \{x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$ and denote its convex hull
$$
C \equiv \bigg\{ \sum_i \lambda_i x_i : \lambda_i \geq 0 \text{ for all } i \text{ and } \sum_i \lambda_i = 1 \bigg\}.
$$

I would like to show that for any $c \in C$, there exists no $c' \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for all $x_i \in X$
$$
\|x_i-c'\|_\infty < \|x_i-c\|_\infty.
$$
In other words, there is no point $c'$ that is simultaneously closer to all the points in $X$ than $c$. Alternatively, if you were to move $c$ closer to some $x_i$, you would automatically move away from another $x_{j}$. Distance is measured using the max-norm, but this probably also holds using other norms.

For instance, in case $X = \{x_1, x_2\}$, I can show for any $c \in C$ that the total distance to $x_1$ and $x_2$ is constant independently of the norm.
Namely,
\begin{align}
\|x_1-c\| + \|x_2-c\| 
&= \| x_1 - (\lambda_1 x_1 + \lambda_2 x_2)\| + \|x_2 - (\lambda_1 x_1 + \lambda_2 x_2)\| \\
&= \|(1-\lambda_1) x_1 - \lambda_2 x_2\| + \|(1-\lambda_2) x_2 - \lambda_1 x_1\| \\
&= \|\lambda_2 ( x_1 - x_2 ) \| + \|\lambda_1 ( x_2 - x_1 ) \| \\
&= (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) \|x_1 - x_2\| \\
&= \|x_1 - x_2\| \\
&= \text{constant}.
\end{align}
As a result, for any other $c' \in C$
\begin{align}
\|x_1 - c'\| < \|x_1 - c\| \implies \|x_2 - c'\| > \|x_2 - c\| ,
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\|x_2 - c'\| < \|x_2 - c\| \implies \|x_1 - c'\| > \|x_1 - c\| .
\end{align}
On the other hand, if $c' \notin C$, the triangle inequality quickly yields a similar result.

This idea does not solve my problem unfortunately as the total distance $\sum_i \|x_i-c\|$ is not constant when there are more than two points in $X$. For instance, consider in $\mathbb{R^2}$ the points $x_1 = (0,0)$, $x_2 = (1,0)$ and $x_3 = (0,1)$, and choose $c=x_1$ and $c'=x_2$.

Would anyone know a way to tackle this problem? It sounds so simple that there must already have been someone else who either proved it or found a counter-example.

Comment: As a side note, there is a nice proof for the $2$-norm: the inequalities $\|x_i-c'\|_2<\|x_i-c\|_2$ imply that all the points $x_i$ all lie on the same side of the perpendicular bisector of the segment $cc'$ as the point $c'$, but that contradicts the fact that $c$ is in their convex hull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is false, here is a counterexample.

Let $x_1=(2,-1,-1)$, $x_2=(-1,2,-1)$ and $x_3=(-1,-1,2)$.
The convex hull of these points contains the origin.
The origin has $\infty$-distance 2 to all these points.
However, the point $c'=(0.5,0.5,0.5)$, has $\infty$-distance 1.5 to all these points.
Hence, for all $x_i\in X$,
$$\|x_i-c'\|_\infty=1.5<2=\|x_i-0\|_\infty$$

Comment: Fun fact: one can show that this $c'$ does not lie in the cone $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider three points $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$, $P_i=(\delta_{ij})$ in  $\mathbb{R}^3$ endowed with the standard $L_p$ norm.

If  $1< p<\infty$  the norm is strictly convex. Therefore the minimization problem

$$\min \sum_{i=1}^3 \|PP_i\|_p$$

has a unique solution $P$. Due to the symmetry, the point $P$ lies on the line $x_1=x_2=x_3$.

Now, it turns out that for $p\ne 2$ the point of minimum is *not* $(1,1,1)$ ( it is not hard to find). By continuity, for $p= \infty$ a point of minimum is $(1/2,1/2,1/2)$.  Hence this point is closer to $P_i$ than the point $(1/3,1/3,1/3)$.

***Added:***  So it seems it works for all $p\ne 2$. For $p=2$ it's just the opposite, this requires another proof.

$\bf{Added:}$ Let's see why this is not true for the $l_p$ norm, $p \ne 2$, in dimension $n> 2$.

Consider $n$ points $P_i = (\delta_{ij})_{1\le j\le n}$, $1\le i \le n$.

The point $P$ with $\sum \|P-P_i\| $ smallest is unique, $P= (t, \ldots, t)$, with

$$t = \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{p-1}}+ 1}$$

For $p \ne 2$, this point $P$ is not in the convex hull of the $P_i$. Now consider the symmetric $P'_i$ of $P_i$ with respect to the $P$.  We get a convex polytope $P_1 \ldots P_n P'_1 \ldots P'_n$ ( a prism) with center $P$. Moreover, for any other point $Q= (s, \ldots, s)$, and any $i$,

$$\delta = \|P-P_i\|< \|Q-P_j\|, \|Q-P'_k\|$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you think the same holds if $c'$ also has to be in $C$?

Comment: Indeed, if $c'$ is also restricted to $C$, just add the point $(1,1,1)$. Both $c=(1/3, 1/3, 1/3)$ and $c'=(1/2, 1/2, 1/2)$ are then part of the convex polytope spanned by $\{ (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1) \}$. However, $c'$ is at a distance of 1/2 of every vertex, whereas $c$ is at 2/3 of each.

Comment: @octave: No worries! And it looks you completed the answer!  Yeah, this symmetric configuration can give other counterexamples.  Now, about the $\ell_2$ case, do you care to know that it is true in fact? It's a great question btw.

Comment: Michal shared an elegant proof for the 2-norm. So it's all figured out now.